# submit appended form containing a contenteditable div on press of enter key

Tags: jquery, html

i want to submit a form which contains a contenteditable div on press of the enter key. the form is appended into a div using jquery .before().

```
<form class="send" id="send_it<?php echo $seed['idd']; ?>" method="post" action="#">
    <div id="input_msg" contenteditable="true" 
          class="input<?php echo $seed['idd']; ?>" 
          style="width:210px; position:fixed; bottom:0;">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="send"  style="display:none;" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do what you want:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode== 13 || e.which== 13) { //if enter key is pressed
        var contentEditableValue=$('#input_msg').text(); //get the div value
        $('.send').append('<input type="hidden" value="'+contentEditableValue+'" id="valueToSend">'); //add a dummy input to the form to send the value
        $('.send').submit(); //submit the form
    }
});
```